# JQuery Full calender basic week view event sorting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have used jquery fullcalender with basicWeek view but also i want to do event sorting for day also can you please help me to solve these issue.

i have used these code in my jquery

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaWeek'

            },
                        defaultView: 'basicWeek',
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
            draggable: true,// this allows things to be draggable onto the calendar
                        editable: true,
            //dragRevertDuration: 0,
            drop: function() {
            },
            eventDragStop: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {

                    }
    });
```

But here i can not sorting the event please provide me the solution for sorting with default week view.

Comment: what do you mean you can't sort the events? It's a calendar, they should appear in date/time order, in the right place on the calendar respective to that. What other ordering/sorting would you want to do?

Comment: issue is the i need to sort event on defaultView: 'basicWeek' calender that i can not do it i need help in that case.

Comment: If your events have got the correct date and time properties, then fullCalendar will sort them by date and time and put them in the right order in the calendar for you when you change to that view. What other sorting do you want to do? It's not clear at all from your description. Give a clear example of the input, and the output you want to achieve.